# Fastlink Landing page is not getting rendered

Tags: yodlee

I am working on implementing Fastlink 2.0 integration for aggregation and IAV for my application. I am able to get the oauth token for both Aggregation and IAV but when I am using it along with the required parameters to render the Fastlink landing page I am getting the response as Cannot get resource.

The steps I followed are as below:

1. Logged in with Cobrand username and password and got the cobrandSessionToken (e.g. 08062013_0:26fe011eff898dc0babb8b54fad90ac522e753c6e4d29b7329eeb67e57b760975a9918d8a913c83a910199e6f1b9dd15652532011100010328dad2e6b29f49b3).
2. Using the demo username/password got the userSessionToken (e.g. 08062013_0:d1958fca493a02fadcad93019ba44bd3563cc4cb437331c60b3df77a4e353ed2137ba641c879a6736a112d613a146438f45fc8a5f5540ffb65ec17dee42fee46 )
3. Using the cobrandSession token, rsession(userSession) token and 10003600 (aggregation) as finappId got the oauth token.
4. Using the token generated in Step 3, rsession(userSession) token generated in Step 2 and app (i.e., finappId) invoke the Yodlee Fastlink using the following url.

https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver

Complete url:

https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver?app%3D10003600%26rsession%3D08062013_0%3A03cfae2bd46624e71b1306cbe9730a8f92085c28657f271f9fa84bf17ccf566428be4da399c2a995e95d1c5527442735398a49d96007826b3a2af118d7b53dc1%26token%3Db3298792d5a43473fa2434ae9c6453dffd74392b4ae0608a75b40922ca3d5325%26redirectReq%3Dtrue%26extraParams%3D

Kindly help if somebody knows how to resolve this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to submit this as an HTML Form post, this is not a REST GET request. This means it will not work if you just append it to the URL and try to get it.

Here is the HTML Form you can replace the respective values-

```html
<div class='center processText'>Processing...</div><div>
<form action='<nodeURL>' method='post' id='rsessionPost'>
RSession : <input type='text' name='rsession' placeholder='rsession' value='06142015_0:9d2817f2164ef0720282fd680c882b188b776d93e4af03155b0508a09ae8e274f0caab5d2d6819bee2ec69c85044410acb356807ba69ecd3e6e28643120dab61' id='rsession'/><br/>
FinappId : <input type='text' name='app' placeholder='FinappId' value='10003620' id='finappId'/><br/>
Redirect : <input type='text' name='redirectReq' placeholder='true/false' value='true'/><br/>
Token : <input type='text' name='token' placeholder='token' value='6ea1ef4aaa1ec923aba38b911a45cbe0019a387837b0a83738ec40a8c9a24613' id='token'/><br/>
Extra Params : <input type='text' name='extraParams' placeholer='Extra Params' value='' id='extraParams'/><br/></form></div>
<script>document.getElementById('rsessionPost').submit();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Apoorv, this can only be done through HTML form post. If you set redirectReq as FALSE and do a HTTP Post you will get the FinAppURL, but the url will never work. If you need to display fastLink 2.0 inside iframe you can can achieve it by setting the form target to the iframe as shown below.

```
<div style="visibility: hidden">
<form action="https://auyirestnode.stage.yodleeinteractive.com/authenticate/private-ausandbox16/?channelAppName=auyirestmaster" method="post" name="rsessionPost" id="rsessionPost" target="yodleeIframe">
    <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="rsession" placeholder="rsession" value="@Model.RSession" id="rsession" /><br />
    <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="app" placeholder="FinappId" value="10003600" id="finappId" /><br />
    <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="redirectReq" placeholder="true/false" value="true" /><br />
    <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="token" placeholder="token" value="@Model.Token" id="token" /><br />
    <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="extraParams" placeholer="Extra Params" value="@Model.ExtraParams" id="extraParams"/>
</form>
```