# Yodlee FastLink "An error occurred while processing the request or session is invalid"

Tags: yodlee

I am working on implementing a FastLink2.0 Integration for aggregation in my application.  I saw from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649041/fastlink-landing-page-is-not-getting-rendered) that the interface needs to be called from an HTML form and not just a simple REST GET request.

I was able to get a simple html page to work and redirect to FastLink, but when I put the page into an iframe (as the [documentation](https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0/FastLink_Integration_Guide_for_Web) recommends), it says "An error occurred while processing the request or session is invalid"

```
<iframe src="fastlink.html"></iframe>
```

fastlink.html:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class='center processText'>Processing...</div>
<div style="visibility: hidden">
    <form action='https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/' method='post' id='rsessionPost'>
        RSession : <input type='text' name='rsession' placeholder='rsession'
                          value='<--user token-->'
                          id='rsession'/><br/>
        FinappId : <input type='text' name='app' placeholder='FinappId' value='10003600' id='finappId'/><br/>
        Redirect : <input type='text' name='redirectReq' placeholder='true/false' value='true'/><br/>
        Token : <input type='text' name='token' placeholder='token'
                       value='<--authenticated token-->' id='token'/><br/>
        Extra Params : <input type='text' name='extraParams' placeholer='Extra Params' value=''
                              id='extraParams'/><br/></form>
</div>
<script>document.getElementById('rsessionPost').submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone figure this out?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to solved this? I am getting same error with fast link.its open the fast link page but after 5-7 seconds its redirect and gives me error like "An error occurred while processing the request or session is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps-

Here is the simple example of how to invoke fastlink in an iframe:

In post.html

```
<div class='center processText'>Processing...</div>
<div>
<form action='https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/' method='post' id='rsessionPost'>  RSession : 
<input type='text' name='rsession' placeholder='rsession' value='08062013_0:829d770b5c7d29e300a7dabc42108383ecac552de57a9706ed4077c98acde1e29e874e676651813a95543b8fb5e2d5face054f300a03b34e7105976867dde3' id='rsession'/>
<br/>   FinappId : 
<input type='text' name='app' placeholder='FinappId' value='10003600' id='finappId'/>
<br/>   Redirect : 
<input type='text' name='redirectReq' placeholder='true/false' value='true'/>
<br/>   Token : 
<input type='text' name='token' placeholder='token' value='7346ddfb28f1eef2acdc4943695680337a3e5ea2ae9bb88c35d0ed58c702b6' id='token'/>
<br/>   Extra Params : 
<input type='text' name='extraParams' placeholer='Extra Params' value='' id='extraParams'/>
<br/>
</form>
</div>
<script>document.getElementById('rsessionPost').submit();
</script>
```

Then invoking this in iframe:

In test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="post.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: Hi,

I've tried your sample code above, replacing the rsession and token with my own, however I still get the response of "An error occurred while processing the request or session is invalid."  When I access the iframe page directly, however, I can successfully load fastlink.
Are you having the same issues?

Comment: So this seems to be a Chrome specific issue.  I was able to confirm the above example works on firefox and safari.
The issue seems to stem from the redirect after the post to "https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/".

Instead of sending a POST to the redirect url: 
"https://node.developer.yodlee.com/apperror/?brand=10010352&app=10003600&appId=<appId>&cookieDisabled=true&version=9.88&status=published"
Chrome sends a GET request.
I'm not sure why, but that's as far as I've gotten.