# channelAppName in Yodlee fastlink 2.0

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to implement fastlink 2.0 and not getting good information from Yodlee Integration document. So looking at following post .

[Fastlink Landing page is not getting rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649041/fastlink-landing-page-is-not-getting-rendered)

What is channelAppName in the link?

Answer (score 0):

channelAppName is the name of the Yodlee's channel, under which you are trying to launch FL2.0. This varies upon the environment/ customer in Yodlee.

```html
Below is the sample HTML Form, you can replace the values here and save it as an HTML page and just open it(for testing). This should launch the FL 2.0 successfully.
 
<div class='center processText'>Processing...</div><div>
<form action='<nodeURL>' method='post' id='rsessionPost'>
RSession : <input type='text' name='rsession' placeholder='rsession' value='06142015_0:9d2817f2164ef0720282fd680c882b188b776d93e4af03155b0508a09ae8e274f0caab5d2d6819bee2ec69c85044410acb356807ba69ecd3e6e28643120dab61' id='rsession'/><br/>
FinappId : <input type='text' name='app' placeholder='FinappId' value='10003600' id='finappId'/><br/>
Redirect : <input type='text' name='redirectReq' placeholder='true/false' value='true'/><br/>
Token : <input type='text' name='token' placeholder='token' value='6ea1ef4aaa1ec923aba38b911a45cbe0019a387837b0a83738ec40a8c9a24613' id='token'/><br/>
Extra Params : <input type='text' name='extraParams' placeholer='Extra Params' value='callback=http://www.yodlee.com' id='extraParams'/><br/></form></div>
<script>document.getElementById('rsessionPost').submit();</script>
 


Node URL which needs to be used to invoke Fastlink 2.0 for this sandbox account: https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/
```

P